# Using async code and RabbitMQ and generate uuid as correlationId, new uuid doesnt appear

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, rabbitmq, uuid

Strange behavior when the uuid is generated and used later. As you can see in the screenshots, the first time works fine, but the second coralationId somehow gets the previous value.

Logs:

```
generate dabe6b23-571f-467e-92ba-be5429af5d78
auth_receive_queue
dabe6b23-571f-467e-92ba-be5429af5d78
dabe6b23-571f-467e-92ba-be5429af5d78
I am here
2
generate 61c34f0e-1b5e-4e55-b7ee-8c9fd48edc17
client_receive_queue
dabe6b23-571f-467e-92ba-be5429af5d78
61c34f0e-1b5e-4e55-b7ee-8c9fd48edc17
4
err.message: Response timeout
```

[image: Source screenshot]

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: It's likely that the value has changed since the promise resolved, perhaps creating the UUID at the time that it is needed to be used would solve the issue?
(Additionally, you should try not post screenshots of code where possible)